# Input Datetime with timezone value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, datetime, input

I have a problem with setting the value of my input datetime-local.
So I have (with JQuery) created this variable:

```
var startfield = $('<input />', {
    type   : 'datetime-local'
    });
startfield.val('2017-04-06T07:24:51');
```

The startfield is filled in correctly, but I have removed the timezone.
Is there a way to include the timezone, when filling in the starfield value.
Or in other words, is there a better input type or a better way to set the value: 2017-04-06T07:24:51.000Z? .000Z is the timezone

Comment: if you want to get the hour of the timezone with this `var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();` if you just want the time you can get it from the computer with `var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();`

Comment: I have an idea, is there an easy way to convert  any given date to a date with timezone Z?

Comment: which format do you want to convert it to?

Comment: @almartinez I pushed enter too fast, check comment above

Comment: http://jibx.sourceforge.net/binding/date-time.html check this, i'm not sure if you mean that, if this is not usefull tell me ( it is the first method shown on the page)

Comment: then i dont know it, srry about it :)